# Is it secure to put a mysqldumped file online?

Tags: databases, mysql

I made a database table of emoji country codes. I exported the data via mysqldump into a file called `countries.sql`.

I want to share it because it was a hassle finding anything like this, so I want to save people the trouble.

No sensitive data is in the table, but in the heading of the file, it seems like some information could be used in a attack, but I'm not really sure. It gives information about the OS and DB engine. I'm sure you could get this information in other ways, but I figured I'd ask before I do.

Here is the heading of the sql file.

```
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: analytics
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: Frame Challenge: Why don't you publish the data in, say, CSV or JSON format?

Answer (score 2):

Basically there is not so much information that attacker can use, but lets see an example scenario:
You will allow users to download the mysql dump file from your web host, and the file will include the operating system and version this may give the attacker ground to step on and try to find exploit for that OS and version, but unless is very outdated there is nothing to worry about.
You can simply remove those lines by yourself or specify it in the software you are using to dump that file(example: phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to save people the trouble.

I would object with another question: **Is it secure to run someone else's SQL file?**

Are you really doing the correct thing by posting a SQL?

I have tried to reverse perspective from producer (you) to consumer (me). This script is very likely innocent and, apart from @mrSotirow's answer, does not pose a particular security risk to your infrastructure.

But the problem is that in the real world, running non-vetted SQL is bad. Especially if the script is to be run **unmanned** by a software that updates itself regularly.

XML, JSON, CSV and flat-files exist for that purpose.

Example: it might be not your case, but assuming this dump was made for a popular software such as WordPress, it would be easy for the producer (you) to inject malicious code. The longer the script, the least possibility someone detects something odd in the middle. Just as `INSERT INTO admins (....)`.

*People* (consumers) can benefit from you providing them data, but *should* take the trouble of converting data to their own format.

Comment: I second this approach. CSV works extremely well for "flat" data like key/value pairs. Besides, it can more easily be imported into a "usable" format, while SQL needs a SQL Database behind it.

Comment: Not to mention that SQL is sometimes dialect-dependent, e.g. for date/times

Answer (score 1):

As a secondary answer, **it is safe** to remove such headers and publish only the plain `INSERT` statements